# Print a string from n through 1 using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to print a string from number n through 1 using this recursive function:

```js
function numStr(n) {
    let outputStr = '';
    
    if (n === 1) {
        return outputStr + n;
    } else {
        outputStr + n;
        return numStr(n-1);
    }
}

console.log(numStr(5));    //should print 54321
```

I know changing the lines 7 and 8 to `return outputStr + n + numStr(n-1)` does the job. But I can't figure out why the above code doesn't work as expected. It prints '1' in all cases.

Comment: Have you tried to step line by line through the code with a debugger? Especially this line `outputStr + n;` could be interesting.

Comment: Yeah, it was a quite trivial problem. Guess I was just being stupid and wasn't paying much attention. I didn't return the "outputStr". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `n!=1` then you are just appending the `n` to a variable `ouputStr` but you are not actually returning this `outputStr` value. Change the code to:

```js
function numStr(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return '1';
    } else {
        return n+numStr(n-1);
    }
}

console.log(numStr(5));    //should print 54321
```

Comment: How didn't I see that! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

I believe outputStr is scoped incorrectly. Every time you call numStr, outputStr is reset to an empty string, so you are only getting the last value of outputStr upon return which is 1.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another recursion that would work:

```js
const numStr=n=>n>0?n+numStr(--n):'';
console.log(numStr(5)); // 54321
```

It becomes clear that the variable `outputString` is not even needed with a proper recursion.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you've made a simple mistake, you wrote

```
outputStr + n;
```

instead of

```
outputStr = outputStr + n;
```

or

```
outputStr += n;
```

Comment: How would this change the result?

Comment: This still won't work. As answered by @WinterSoldier I just forgot to return the string due to which only 1 is being returned in every case.